# Date format issue in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have used below code to format the date in Highcharts,

```
Highcharts.dateFormats = {
    W: function (timestamp) {
        var date = new Date(timestamp),
            day = date.getUTCDay() == 0 ? 7 : date.getUTCDay(),
            dayNumber;
            date.setDate(date.getUTCDate() + 4 - day);
            dayNumber = Math.ceil((date.getTime() - new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), 1, 1, 0)) / 86400000);
        //console.log(dayNumber);
        console.log(Math.floor(dayNumber / 7));
        return Math.floor(dayNumber / 7);
    }
}
```

but the week order comes as follows - `0,4,8,12,17,21,26,30,34,39,43,47`

Date format is supposed to come as follows - `0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52'

what went wrong in my code and any idea why after `12` it increases by `5` and sets it `17'?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: you could include the momentjs library and do `moment(timestamp).week();`

Comment: will that solve my week formatting issue?

Comment: if I understand correctly this function is supposed to get the week number from the timestamp, momentjs can manage this for you

Comment: Could you show us live example of your issue? You may have problem with your data.

Comment: unfortunately i am unable to create a live fiddle as the chart is depend on SQL data. but i am sure that these date values does not depends on the real data. it works only with this formatter i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Week numbers that you are getting seems to meet the ISO definitions.
Please check this out for further reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Have created a sample http://jsfiddle.net/pmajhwar/bzv5k6L8/ that would help expert inputs and faster resolution. Hope this helps.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>



 $(function() {
  Highcharts.dateFormats = {
    W: function(timestamp) {
      var date = new Date(timestamp),
        day = date.getUTCDay() == 0 ? 7 : date.getUTCDay(),
        dayNumber;
      date.setDate(date.getUTCDate() + 4 - day);
      dayNumber = Math.ceil((date.getTime() - new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), 1, 1, 0)) / 86400000);
      console.log("UTC " + moment('2016-01-01').utc() + " " + Date.UTC(2016, 1, 1))
      var week = moment(date, 'lll').utc().isoWeek();
      // var week = moment(date, 'llll').utc().week();
      console.log("date: " + moment(date).utc().format('llll') + " wk " + Math.floor(dayNumber / 7) + "  moment wk-> " + week);
      //return Math.floor(dayNumber / 7) ;
      return week;


    }
  }

  var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container'
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Custom date format'
    },

    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 36e5, // one week
      labels: {
        format: '{value:Week %W/%Y}',
        align: 'right',
        rotation: -30
      }
    },

    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0],
      pointInterval: 7 * 24 * 36e5,
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1)

    }]

  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and time!! but i cant use highstock in my application.

Comment: you need not, this sample hopefully would help get inputs on the underlying issue with the Highcharts.dateFormats, i tried couple of things but it seems that we might need our own custom week implementation